# Is there a query generator or extension point for QueryOver like there is for LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to use calculated properties that I use with `Query<T>()` inside of a `QueryOver<T>()`. When using a LINQ query, I can register custom generators with a custom `DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry`. This works great for [calculated properties from an expression](http://hendryluk.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/nhibernate-linq-ing-calculated-properties/) so the code isn't duplicated.

I can't seem to find the extension point for registering custom generators for the QueryOver API. Does it exist?

I'd like to *not* have to duplicate the calculated property logic inside of a raw SQL string (`Map(x => x.Prop).Formula("query").LazyLoad().Access.ReadOnly()`). This would means twice the logic and twice the number of tests.

From what I've seen through the [source](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core), the QueryOver API uses Criterion as its base... which directly translates to raw SQL rather than HQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq and QueryOver take different paths to sql:

```
QueryOver -> Expression -> Criteria \
Linq      -> LinqParser -> Hql      --> Sql
```

for Criteria there is `NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomMethodCall(...);` which might be what you want.

A simple example:

```
public static class QueryOverExtensions
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(() => QueryOverExtensions.Day(default(DateTime)), QueryOverExtensions.ProcessDay);
        ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(() => QueryOverExtensions.Month(default(DateTime)), QueryOverExtensions.ProcessMonth);
        ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(() => QueryOverExtensions.Year(default(DateTime)), QueryOverExtensions.ProcessYear);
    }

    public static Int32 Day(this DateTime dateTimeProperty)
    {
        return (dateTimeProperty.Day);
    }

    public static Int32 Month(this DateTime dateTimeProperty)
    {
        return (dateTimeProperty.Month);
    }

    public static Int32 Year(this DateTime dateTimeProperty)
    {
        return (dateTimeProperty.Year);
    }

    private static IProjection ProcessDay(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    {
        IProjection property = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).AsProjection();
        return (Projections.SqlFunction("day", NHibernateUtil.Int32, property));
    }

    private static IProjection ProcessMonth(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    {
        IProjection property = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).AsProjection();
        return (Projections.SqlFunction("month", NHibernateUtil.Int32, property));
    }

    private static IProjection ProcessYear(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    {
        IProjection property = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).AsProjection();
        return (Projections.SqlFunction("year", NHibernateUtil.Int32, property));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call Register(). After that you can use it like this:

```
session.QueryOver<Order>().Where(o => o.Date.Month() == DateTime.Today.Month).List();
```

Comment: Yes I found this just the other night while looking through the source. The largest problem is that it requires a separate `Expression` to `ICriteria` processors. I'll see what I come up with and then let you know.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
public static class QueryOverExtensions
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(() => QueryOverExtensions.Day(default(DateTime)), QueryOverExtensions.ProcessDay);
        ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(() => QueryOverExtensions.Month(default(DateTime)), QueryOverExtensions.ProcessMonth);
        ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(() => QueryOverExtensions.Year(default(DateTime)), QueryOverExtensions.ProcessYear);
    }

    public static Int32 Day(this DateTime dateTimeProperty)
    {
        return (dateTimeProperty.Day);
    }

    public static Int32 Month(this DateTime dateTimeProperty)
    {
        return (dateTimeProperty.Month);
    }

    public static Int32 Year(this DateTime dateTimeProperty)
    {
        return (dateTimeProperty.Year);
    }

    private static IProjection ProcessDay(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    {
        IProjection property = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).AsProjection();
        return (Projections.SqlFunction("day", NHibernateUtil.Int32, property));
    }

    private static IProjection ProcessMonth(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    {
        IProjection property = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).AsProjection();
        return (Projections.SqlFunction("month", NHibernateUtil.Int32, property));
    }

    private static IProjection ProcessYear(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    {
        IProjection property = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).AsProjection();
        return (Projections.SqlFunction("year", NHibernateUtil.Int32, property));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call Register(). After that you can use it like this:

```
session.QueryOver<Order>().Where(o => o.Date.Month() == DateTime.Today.Month).List();
```

Comment: Would you mind merging this with the upvoted answer? I was just working on an example myself, but you've already done it :).